Could not find the correct Provider<> above this BlocListener<, > Widget
I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter application:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<SettingsBloc> above this BlocListener<SettingsBloc, SettingsState> Widget.
I'm using the GetIt and Injectable packages for dependency injection. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
settings_bloc.dart
@lazySingleton
class SettingsBloc extends HydratedBloc<SettingsEvent, SettingsState> { 
  // Bloc implementation
}

settings_page.dart
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous.locale != current.locale,
      listener: (context, state) => context.setLocale(state.locale),
      child: BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

app_router.dart
GoRoute(
  path: '/tools',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
    key: state.pageKey,
    child: ToolsPage(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
        FadeThroughTransition(
      animation: animation,
      secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
      child: child,
    ),
  ),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: 'settings',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: BlocProvider.value(
          value: getIt<SettingsBloc>(),
          child: const SettingsPage(),
        ),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, primaryAnimation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
            FadeThroughTransition(
          animation: primaryAnimation,
          secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'theme_selection',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const ThemeSelectionPage(),
            transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                FadeThroughTransition(
              animation: animation,
              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),

injection.config.dart
extension GetItInjectableX on GetIt {
  GetIt init({
    String? environment,
    EnvironmentFilter? environmentFilter,
  }) {
    final gh = GetItHelper(
      this,
      environment,
      environmentFilter,
    );
    final injectableModule = _$InjectableModule();
    gh.factory<FirebaseAuth>(() => injectableModule.firebaseAuth);
    gh.factory<GoogleSignIn>(() => injectableModule.googleSignIn);
    gh.singleton<Logger>(() => injectableModule.logger);
    gh.singleton<NotificationService>(() => injectableModule.notificationService);
    gh.lazySingleton<SettingsBloc>(() => SettingsBloc());
    // Other dependencies...
    return this;
  }
}

class _$InjectableModule extends InjectableModule {}

Issue:
When navigating to the SettingsPage, I receive the error stating that the Provider<SettingsBloc> cannot be found above the BlocListener. I've ensured that SettingsBloc is registered as a lazySingleton in GetIt and provided it using BlocProvider.value in the router.
Question:
What could be causing the Provider<SettingsBloc> not to be found above the BlocListener, and how can I resolve this issue to ensure that SettingsBloc is properly provided to the SettingsPage?
I attempted to wrap the MaterialApp.router() with a MultiBlocProvider and include SettingsBloc as one of the providers. Here is the code snippet:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<AuthBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => SettingsBloc()),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp.router(
      // ... other configurations
    ),
  );
}


Anywhere you are using BlocListener or BlocBuilder or BlocConsumer, you can provide your bloc object like this (with GetIt):
          BlocListener(
            bloc: getIt<AuthBloc>(),
            listener: ...,
          ),


Thank you for your suggestion. I have added the bloc parameter to the BlocListener, but now I'm encountering a new error:
Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type SettingsBloc is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
As you can see, my injection.config.dart file generated by Injectable does register SettingsBloc as a lazySingleton. Additionally, all my other injectables are functioning correctly without any issues. Only SettingsBloc seems to be causing this problem.

@MiltonMariños you need to call the GetIt setup function in the main function in your Flutter project. In your code, I am not familiar with GetItInjectableX extension but according to this example link you will find the way.

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<AuthBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => getIt<SettingsBloc>()), // <-- Change here
    ],
    child: MaterialApp.router(
      // ... other configurations
    ),
  );
}

As you have tagged your SettingsBloc as lazySingleton, I assume that you want to use it via service locator, not with direct creation

I have tried what you say and it still does not work.

try to run your application in debug mode, and open widget tree, there you can find the actual bloc provider and see what comes inside of this provider. If your widget is not inside, then you can not use the bloc
